# Marcador de goles con una pelota que rebota

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un simulador de una pelota que rebota y le quise agregar cosas como una portería y que si se mete marque gol y de puntos.

Pero en el caso del "Equipo rojo" marca dos puntos pues el ciclo if se hace dos veces, el cual no entiendo cómo evitar que pase esto.

Todo está bien con "azul" la lógica es si `x == 0 && y >= 125 && y <= 175` marca gol 1 punto, pero en caso del "equipo rojo" si `x == 480 && y >= 125 && y <= 175` en este caso no pasa nada pues 480 no puede ser, está fuera del contenedor (no sé porque) entonces, siempre está menos el tamaño de desplazamiento del balón, en este caso 5px.

Entonces la lógica es `si x == 475 && y >= 125 && y <= 175` y ahora si marca gol, pero dos veces, 2 puntos.

El ciclo if se cumple dos veces pues el 475 se repite y se cumple pero si pongo si `x == 476 && y >= 125 && y <= 175 ó x == 477` .. no pasa nada.

¿Me pueden ayudar a explicarme qué pasa?, porque no funciona, ¿por qué no acepta el 480px? ya intenté poner en vez de 5px a 1px pero es igual, marca dos veces (pasa dos veces por la misma coordenada 475).

Anexo código:

```js
// Simulador 6
var x = 0;
var xLimite = 0;
var y = 0;
var yLimite = 0;
var azul = 0,
  rojo = 0;

function jugar() {
  var ciclo = setInterval(mover, 30);
}

function mover() {
  //EJE X
  if (xLimite == 0) {
    document.getElementById('pelota').style.marginLeft = x + "px";
    x += 5;

    if (x >= 480) {
      xLimite = 1;
    }
  }

  if (xLimite == 1) {
    document.getElementById('pelota').style.marginLeft = x + "px";
    x -= 5;

    if (x <= 0) {
      xLimite = 0;
    }
  }


  //EJE Y
  if (yLimite == 0) {
    document.getElementById('pelota').style.marginTop = y + "px";
    y += 5;

    if (y >= 280) {
      yLimite = 1;
    }
  }

  if (yLimite == 1) {
    document.getElementById('pelota').style.marginTop = y + "px";
    y -= 5;

    if (y <= 0) {
      yLimite = 0;
    }
  }


  //JUEGO 500x por 300y
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  if (x == 0 && y >= 125 && y <= 175) {
    azul += 2;
    audio.play();
  }

  if (x == 475 && y >= 125 && y <= 175) {
    rojo += 1;
    audio.play();
  }

  document.getElementById('marcador').innerHTML = "Equipo Azul: " + azul + " Equipo Rojo: " + rojo;
}
```

```css
/*  Simulador 6   */

.publicoFutbol {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 230px;
}

#contenedor {
  background-image: url("http://netliguista.com/img/org/campo-futbol.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#pelota {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

#audio {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a name="sim6"></a>
<article class="sim6">
  <header>
    <h3>Simulador 6: ¡Juego Futbol!</h3>
  </header>

  <p class="usuario" id="saludo5">Hola </p>
  <p class="usuario"> este es un simulador de pelota <br><br> Como jugar:</p>

  <section>
    <div id="contenedor">
      <img id="pelota" src="https://www.tenvinilo.com/vinilos-decorativos/img/preview/vinilo-infantil-pelota-futbol-color-1399.png">
    </div>

    <button id="jugar" onclick="jugar()">GO</button>

    <label id="marcador"> - </label>

    <audio id="audio">
            <source src="musica/gol.aac" type="audio/aac">
     </audio>

  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: Bienvenido Charles. Si tienes en línea los recursos a los que hace referencia tu código, sería bueno que agregaras `<base>` para que se aprecie mejor el resultado del mismo en Stack Snippet.

Comment: Listo, agregue las imágenes faltantes. ¿Qué es el Stack Snippet? ¿El visualizador?

Comment: Sí, "el visualizador". En otras palabras, Stack Snippet es el nombre con el algunos nos referimos a la herramienta de edición y ejecución de fragmento de código HTML/CSS/JavaScript incluida en el editor de preguntas y respuestas de este sitio.

Answer (score 1):

En la pregunta se indica que

> pero en caso del "equipo rojo" si x == 480 && y >= 125 && y <= 175 en este caso no pasa nada pues 480 no puede ser, esta fuera del contenedor (no se porque)

En realidad si pasa, sólo que tarda un poco.

A continuación el código del OP con cambios mínimos (se señalan con comentarios)

```js
// Simulador 6

var x = 0;

var xLimite = 0;

var y = 0;

var yLimite = 0;

var azul = 0,
  rojo = 0;



function jugar() {

  var ciclo = setInterval(mover, 30);

}



function mover() {



  //EJE X

  if (xLimite == 0) {

    document.getElementById('pelota').style.marginLeft = x + "px";

    x += 5;

    if (x >= 480) {

      xLimite = 1;

    }

  } else {

    document.getElementById('pelota').style.marginLeft = x + "px";

    x -= 5;

    if (x <= 0) {

      xLimite = 0;

    }

  }



  //EJE Y

  if (yLimite == 0) {

    document.getElementById('pelota').style.marginTop = y + "px";

    y += 5;

    if (y >= 280) {

      yLimite = 1;

    }

  }

  if (yLimite == 1) {

    document.getElementById('pelota').style.marginTop = y + "px";

    y -= 5;

    if (y <= 0) {

      yLimite = 0;

    }

  }



  //JUEGO 500x por 300y



  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

  if (x == 0 && y >= 125 && y <= 175) {

    azul += 1;  // Línea modificada

    audio.play();

  }



  if (x == 480 && y >= 125 && y <= 175) { // Línea modificada

    rojo += 1;

    audio.play();

  }



  document.getElementById('marcador').innerHTML = "Equipo Azul: " + azul + " Equipo Rojo: " + rojo;

}
```

```css
/*  Simulador 6   */

.publicoFutbol {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 230px;
}

#contenedor {
  background-image: url("http://netliguista.com/img/org/campo-futbol.png");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#pelota {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
 
}

#audio {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a name="sim6"></a>

<article class="sim6">

  <header>
    <h3>Simulador 6: ¡Juego Futbol!</h3>
  </header>

  <p class="usuario" id="saludo5">Hola </p>

  <p class="usuario"> este es un simulador de pelota <br><br> Como jugar:</p>

  <section>

    <div id="contenedor">

      <img id="pelota" src="https://www.tenvinilo.com/vinilos-decorativos/img/preview/vinilo-infantil-pelota-futbol-color-1399.png">

    </div>

    <button id="jugar" onclick="jugar()">GO</button>

    <label id="marcador"> - </label>

    <audio id="audio">

            <source src="musica/gol.aac" type="audio/aac">

        </audio>

  </section>

</article>
```

Para hacer más evidente, el siguiente se pone la pelota en el centro de la cancha y sólo se desplaza horizontalmente.

```js
// Simulador 6

var x = 240;

var xLimite = 0;

var y = 140;

var yLimite = 0;

var azul = 0,
  rojo = 0;



function jugar() {

  var ciclo = setInterval(mover, 30);

}



function mover() {



  //EJE X

  if (xLimite == 0) {

    document.getElementById('pelota').style.marginLeft = x + "px";

    x += 5;

    if (x >= 480) {

      xLimite = 1;

    }

  } else {

    document.getElementById('pelota').style.marginLeft = x + "px";

    x -= 5;

    if (x <= 0) {

      xLimite = 0;

    }

  }



  //EJE Y

  if (yLimite == 0) {

    document.getElementById('pelota').style.marginTop = y + "px";

    // y += 5;

    if (y >= 280) {

      yLimite = 1;

    }

  }

  if (yLimite == 1) {

    document.getElementById('pelota').style.marginTop = y + "px";

     // y -= 5; 
    
    if (y <= 0) {

      yLimite = 0;

    }

  }



  //JUEGO 500x por 300y



  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

  if (x == 0 && y >= 125 && y <= 175) {

    azul += 1;  // Línea modificada

    audio.play();

  }



  if (x == 480 && y >= 125 && y <= 175) { // Línea modificada

    rojo += 1;

    audio.play();

  }



  document.getElementById('marcador').innerHTML = "Equipo Azul: " + azul + " Equipo Rojo: " + rojo;

}
```

```css
/*  Simulador 6   */

.publicoFutbol {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 230px;
}

#contenedor {
  background-image: url("http://netliguista.com/img/org/campo-futbol.png");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#pelota {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
 
}

#audio {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a name="sim6"></a>

<article class="sim6">

  <header>
    <h3>Simulador 6: ¡Juego Futbol!</h3>
  </header>

  <p class="usuario" id="saludo5">Hola </p>

  <p class="usuario"> este es un simulador de pelota <br><br> Como jugar:</p>

  <section>

    <div id="contenedor">

      <img id="pelota" src="https://www.tenvinilo.com/vinilos-decorativos/img/preview/vinilo-infantil-pelota-futbol-color-1399.png">

    </div>

    <button id="jugar" onclick="jugar()">GO</button>

    <label id="marcador"> - </label>

    <audio id="audio">

            <source src="musica/gol.aac" type="audio/aac">

        </audio>

  </section>

</article>
```

En cuanto al problema de marcar "goles dobles" en el caso del equipo rojo, se debe a que al regresar la pelota pasa de nuevo por la coordenada que se estaba indicando, entonces de ida marca un gol y de vuelta el segundo.